# UK Train information API?

Tags: c#, java, ruby, web-services

I want to add some train journey pricing details into a UK tourist event app I'm planning.

Does anyone know of an API that will provide train timetable and pricing details?  The kind of information we can get through thetrainline.com or raileasy - although I don't need any booking facilities.  Google hasn't turned up much information on the matter...

Not too fussed about what the api is written in, as I can wrap it if required :)

Answer (score 6):

ATOC, who operate National Rail Enquiries, own this data. You'd need to license it from them. [General T&Cs are here](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/terms/).

If it's a not-for-profit endeavour, they may turn a blind eye to screenscraping type operations, as I believe they do with http://traintimes.org.uk/

Comment: Cheers - I was trying to avoid screen-scraping, but it is not-for-profit so we'll see... ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's the National Rail Enquiries API, but you'd have to pay for licensing for that - the Association of Train Operating Companies objected to someone who tried to create an Android widget to present departure times & then had the SOAP headers changed so that it requires a token which they'll give out to registered users. For licensing details you should contact nrelicensing@atoc.org.

The situation's similar with the Trainline.com's Trainline Connect API: http://www.thetrainline.com/press-office/ttl_agency_services_050208.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Note that schedules (but not costs) are available from Network Rail via their datafeeds, with a different license. The license is here: https://www.networkrail.co.uk/terms-and-conditions/ - I've only skimmed it, but I think you're ok for commercial use.

The datafeeds wiki has recently moved and is now here: https://wiki.openraildata.com/index.php/Rail_Data_FAQ

Using the schedule data in XML format probably makes most sense, but if you do want to use it in CIF format I have written a parser for it, here: https://github.com/Chris-MorrisUK/yetAnotherCifParser

I've also just noticed how old your question and the other replies are, this wouldn't have been true at the time you asked.